# Passing field data to use as polygon style setting + Google Fusion Table Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Help!

Essentially what I'm trying to do is use the "Use color specified in a column" option from the configure map styles UI in the API, a "hopeful" workaround of the google 5 category limit.

I have a field of colors that define the different categories and I want to set to individual polygons to the color set in that field. I have a listener and the concept works perfect for the polygon clicked, however it only changes the clicked polygon, it doesn't work the same for the other polygons. I'm pretty new to javascript/sql and fusion tables so I can imagine I'm doing a lot of things wrong, but luckily most of it has been working for the most part. Below is the general idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function(e) { 
var county = e.row["name"].value;
suppressInfoWindows:true
    layer.setOptions({
    query: {
    select: 'geometry',
          from: '3609287'
        },
        styles: [{
          polygonOptions : {
            fillColor: row["PerChngColor"].value
          },
          where: "name = " + county,
          polygonOptions : {<br/>
            strokeColor: "#FF9900",
            strokeWeight: 5,<br/>
            fillColor: String(e.row["PerChngColor"].value)
          }
      }]
  });
  });
```

The first fillColor:row["PerChngColor"].value  is really what I'm trying to get work. It is "supposed" to set the color for the polygon. The second one works great. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Keith W

Comment: So, if I understand correctly,  you want a certain fill color to be applied to all polygons when one of the polygons is clicked? and currently only the polygon that is clicked is the one that is changing color.

Comment: I want to be able to apply the color assigned t each individual polygon. My example is here:                  http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://ui.uncc.edu/display/population-change-2010-2011-nc-sc&usg=AFQjCNEacWe03qfUxQtF8j5fI3NxoqNUlw                                            But this example is rendered in google. I want to be able to call the data from the cell into the api and set it there. That Way I could have multiple color fields and have a drop down menu to select which field you were calling from. Right now this map is static colorwise

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few syntax errors in the code you posted, not sure if that's the issue.  But ...

```
suppressInfoWindows: true.
```

This should throw a JS syntax error.  As should

```
polygonOption: {<br/>`  
 ...
strokeWeight: 5,<br/>
```

Finally, the line where you have.

```
fillColor: row["PerChngColor"].value
```

Should probably be:

```
fillColor: e.row["PerChngColor"].value
```

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post on SO. Those <br/> aren't in my code, Not getting any syntax errors. The problem with the e.row["PerChngColor"].value  is that e is going to throw the id code of the county at the field and only retrieve that county. I want all the records to be retrieved and passed back.